# How can MATLAB use the inputdlg function to process a symbolic function input?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm using **MATLAB R2016b - student edition** to develop an m-file which takes as input a symbolic differential equation, f(t,y), and outputs a slope field and solution curve based on an initial condition. The code is

```
prompt={'dy/dt =','tspan','y0 ='};
title='Slope Field Calculator'; 
answer=inputdlg(prompt,title);
tspan = str2num(answer{2}); %#ok<*ST2NM>
y0 = str2double(answer{3});
syms t y
f = symfun(sym(answer{1}),[t,y]);
[t,y] = ode45(f, tspan, y0);
hold on
dirfield(f,-5:.3:5,-5,.3:5)
plot(t,y,'b','LineWidth',2)
```

The `dirfield(f,-5:.3:5,-5:.3:5)` function has input `f` as an @ function, or an inline function, or the name of an m-file with quotes. The `dirfield` function then plots a direction field for a first order ODE of the form y' = f(t,y) using t-values from t1 to t2 with spacing of dt and using y-values from y1 to y2 with spacing of dy.

According to MATLAB help, the `ode45` function solves differential equations.
`[TOUT,YOUT] = ode45(ODEFUN,TSPAN,Y0)` with `TSPAN = [T0 TFINAL]` then integrates the differential equation y' = f(t,y) from time `T0` to `TFINAL` with initial conditions `Y0`. The input `ODEFUN` is a function handle. For a scalar T and a vector Y, `ODEFUN(T,Y)` must return a column vector corresponding to f(t,y).

When I run the code, the dialogue box runs nicely and accepts my inputs. But when I click "OK", the code throws this error:

```
Warning: Support of character vectors that are not valid variable names or 
define a number will be removed in a
future release. To create symbolic expressions, first create symbolic 
variables and then use operations on them. 
> In sym>convertExpression (line 1559)
  In sym>convertChar (line 1464)
  In sym>tomupad (line 1216)
  In sym (line 179)
  In SlopeFieldsSolutionCurves (line 9) 
Undefined function 'exist' for input arguments of type 'symfun'.

Error in odearguments (line 59)
  if (exist(ode)==2)

Error in ode45 (line 115)
    odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, 
varargin);

Error in SlopeFieldsSolutionCurves (line 10)
[t,y] = ode45(f, tspan, y0);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ode45` takes a function handle, not a symbolic function. Use [matlabFunction](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) instead:

```
[t,y] = ode45(matlabFunction(f), tspan, y0);
```

To get rid of the first warning, you need to define `f` a bit differently:

```
f = evalin( symengine, answer{1} );
f = symfun( f, [t,y] );
```

Comment: Thank you @Sheljohn! This tip got me much farther and works perfectly for the ode45 function. There was a new error caused by the dirfield function, but when I applied the `matlabFunction` to the `f` in the dirfield function, it worked perfectly!